# How to update versioneer version prefix?

Tags: python, python-versioneer

This question probably has been asked before, but I cannot find anything related with the stackoverflow search tool.

The problem is that `versioneer` ignores version update in `setup.cfg`:

```
[versioneer]
vcs = git
versionfile_source = ms_mint/_version.py
versionfile_build = ms_mint/_version.py
tag_prefix = 0.0.31
parentdir_prefix = ms_mint-
```

I had this issue before and then after several tries it disappeared and worked totally at random. I am not sure what causes this. I deleted all `egg-info` files and `__pycache__` directories. But it is still using `0.0.30` as version.

My `setup.py` imports the version like this:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

from ms_mint._version import get_versions
__version__ = get_versions()['version']
```

What else do I have to do other than updating the `setup.cfg`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the tag-prefix can be overwritten by setting a tag with git.

```
git tag 0.0.31
```

Followed by

```
pip install -e .
```

Finally, changed the version number.